# How do I move a submit button to below a form

Tags: css

I want to move the "Not got account" submit button to below the form but not sure what I am doing wrong

I think it is the CSS for .box but not sure how to edit it so it moves the button below and I tried using div tags to move it and they did not work.

Is there a bit of code in my CSS that is keeping it in the centre

I would like to keep it in the same style

Any help would be greatly appreiated

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    background: #191919;
}

body {
    background: #191919, #f5f5f5;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 100;
    width 100vw; 
    height 100vh;
}



.box {
    width: 400px;
    padding: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background: #191919;
    text-align: center;
}



.box h1 {
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.box input[type="text"],
.box input[type="password"] .box input[type="email"] {
    border: 0;
    background: none;
    display: block;
    margin: 20px auto;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid #3498db;
    padding: 14px 10px;
    width: 200px;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 24px;
    transition: 0.25s;
}

.box input[type="text"]:focus,
.box input[type="password"]:focus .box input[type="email"]:focus {
    width: 280px;
    border-color: #2ecc71;
}

.box input[type="submit"] {
    border: 0;
    background: none;
    display: block;
    margin: 20px auto;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid #2ecc71;
    padding: 14px 40px;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 24px;
    transition: 0.25s;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.box input[type="submit"]:hover {
    background: #2ecc71;
}
```

```html
<html>


<form class="box" action="login.php" method="post">
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <input type="text" name="u_email" placeholder="Email">
    <input type="password" name="u_pass" placeholder="Password">
    <input type="submit" name="u_btn" value="Login">
</form>

    
    <div id="right-bar">

<form  class="box" action="register.php" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" name="" value="Not got an Account?">
</form>
</div>



</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the 2nd form uses the same class `box` which centers the element with the first one.

```css
.box {
    ...
    top: 50%;  <--- this is the problem
    left: 50%;
    ...
}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    background: #191919;
}

body {
    background: #191919, #f5f5f5;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 100;
    width 100vw; 
    height 100vh;
}



.box {
    width: 400px;
    padding: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background: #191919;
    text-align: center;
}



.box h1 {
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.box input[type="text"],
.box input[type="password"] .box input[type="email"] {
    border: 0;
    background: none;
    display: block;
    margin: 20px auto;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid #3498db;
    padding: 14px 10px;
    width: 200px;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 24px;
    transition: 0.25s;
}

.box input[type="text"]:focus,
.box input[type="password"]:focus .box input[type="email"]:focus {
    width: 280px;
    border-color: #2ecc71;
}

.box input[type="submit"] {
    border: 0;
    background: none;
    display: block;
    margin: 20px auto;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid #2ecc71;
    padding: 14px 40px;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 24px;
    transition: 0.25s;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.box input[type="submit"]:hover {
    background: #2ecc71;
}

.box2 {
    padding: 0px;
    top: 90%;
}
```

```html
<html>


<form class="box" action="login.php" method="post">
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <input type="text" name="u_email" placeholder="Email">
    <input type="password" name="u_pass" placeholder="Password">
    <input type="submit" name="u_btn" value="Login">
</form>

    
    <div id="right-bar">

<form  class="box box2" action="register.php" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" name="" value="Not got an Account?">
</form>
</div>



</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just don't position your boxes absolute. Makes it quite difficult to get the positioning right.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    background: #191919;
}

body {
    background: #191919, #f5f5f5;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 100;
    width 100vw; 
    height 100vh;
}



.box {
    width: 400px;
    padding: 40px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #191919;
    text-align: center;
}



.box h1 {
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.box input[type="text"],
.box input[type="password"] .box input[type="email"] {
    border: 0;
    background: none;
    display: block;
    margin: 20px auto;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid #3498db;
    padding: 14px 10px;
    width: 200px;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 24px;
    transition: 0.25s;
}

.box input[type="text"]:focus,
.box input[type="password"]:focus .box input[type="email"]:focus {
    width: 280px;
    border-color: #2ecc71;
}

.box input[type="submit"] {
    border: 0;
    background: none;
    display: block;
    margin: 20px auto;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid #2ecc71;
    padding: 14px 40px;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 24px;
    transition: 0.25s;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.box input[type="submit"]:hover {
    background: #2ecc71;
}
```

```html
<html>


<form class="box" action="login.php" method="post">
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <input type="text" name="u_email" placeholder="Email">
    <input type="password" name="u_pass" placeholder="Password">
    <input type="submit" name="u_btn" value="Login">
</form>

    
    <div id="right-bar">

<form  class="box" action="register.php" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" name="" value="Not got an Account?">
</form>
</div>



</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but position absolute in your form is not the best use in this case. You can read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position
Anyway, I made some adjustments in your code: I added a div container for the whole page and made some changes in your css as well. You can check it out in the demo below.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  background: #191919;
}

body {
  background: #191919, #f5f5f5;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 100;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.main-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box {
  margin-top: 10%;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 40px;
  /* position: absolute; */
  /* top: 50%;
  left: 50%; */
  /* transform: translate(-50%, -50%); */
  background: #191919;
  text-align: center;
}

.box h1 {
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.box input[type="text"],
.box input[type="password"] .box input[type="email"] {
  border: 0;
  background: none;
  display: block;
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid #3498db;
  padding: 14px 10px;
  width: 200px;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 24px;
  transition: 0.25s;
}

.box input[type="text"]:focus,
.box input[type="password"]:focus .box input[type="email"]:focus {
  width: 280px;
  border-color: #2ecc71;
}

.box input[type="submit"] {
  border: 0;
  background: none;
  display: block;
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid #2ecc71;
  padding: 14px 40px;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 24px;
  transition: 0.25s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.box input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background: #2ecc71;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="main-container">
      <form class="box" action="login.php" method="post">
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <input type="text" name="u_email" placeholder="Email" />
        <input type="password" name="u_pass" placeholder="Password" />
        <input type="submit" name="u_btn" value="Login" />
      </form>

      <div id="right-bar">
        <form class="box" action="register.php" method="POST">
          <input type="submit" name="" value="Not got an Account?" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```